# Java illegal start of expression and 'else' without 'if' syntax errors

Tags: java, syntax

I'm getting the errors: illegal start of expression and 'else' without 'if' but can't find any syntax errors here.

```
    public int faultyMethod2(int a, int b) {
    int result;

    if((a == 0) || b > 0)) {
        result = (b / a);
    }
    else if (a < 0) {
        result = (a + b);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: unbalanced parenthesis in the first if. delete one of the )

Answer (score 1):

You just have a typo at `if((a == 0) || b > 0)) {` that should be `if((a == 0) || (b > 0)) {`. You missed a bracket.

And later on you need to have the default value of `result`. Either you can give the in declaration part or you need to provide an else part and give the  default value there.

```
 public int faultyMethod2(int a, int b) {
    int result = 0;

    if((a == 0) || b > 0)) {
        result = (b / a);
    }
    else if (a < 0) {
        result = (a + b);
    }

return result;
```

}

or

```
 public int faultyMethod2(int a, int b) {
    int result;

    if((a == 0) || b > 0)) {
        result = (b / a);
    }
    else if (a < 0) {
        result = (a + b);
    }else {
       result = 0;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: That will be the OP's next problem. The current problem is the extra `)`.

Comment: @PaulBoddington He missed a bracket.

Comment: Missed a start paren, or an end paren too many, either way they are unbalanced. Next issue: `if (a == 0) { result = b / a }` causes division by zero. But then again, OP did name it `faultyMethod2`. ;-)